# URL is not loading in Chrome

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

Can anyone give me the best solution for loading an angularJS page?

Because when I am trying to load a page on a browser I am facing an issue: It opens browser but doesn't load the site.

The URL I had given in my config file is

```
seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
baseUrl: "URL ",
```

and in Spec file it is as

```
 browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
 browser.driver.get("//URL");
```

Let me know of any best solution and any missing things in the code.

Comment: The error is -Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: Remove this line browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); and try if is working it is possible the first page to be not angular.

Answer (score 1):

In the protractor.conf.js file, your baseUrl should be some valid URL for your application like

```
baseUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
```

And you navigate to pages like

```
browser.get('http://www.google.com');
or
browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
```

Or if you want to use the webdriver native function instead of protractor's, it would be

```
browser.driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```